# Highlight of the scroll-spy elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an unusual sticky menu that works a bit like a table of content. After using the following JS + CSS code when I click on a menu item it takes me to the anchor but the item in the menu does not highlight.

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  const nav = document.querySelector('nav');
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
  let currentSectionIndex = 0;
  let isScrollingDown = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    if (sections[i].getBoundingClientRect().top <= 0) {
      currentSectionIndex = i;
    }
  }

  if (window.scrollY > this.oldScroll) {
    isScrollingDown = true;
  } else {
    isScrollingDown = false;
  }
  this.oldScroll = window.scrollY;

  if (isScrollingDown) {
    if (
      sections[currentSectionIndex + 1] &&
      sections[currentSectionIndex + 1].getBoundingClientRect().top <= 80
    ) {
      currentSectionIndex++;
    }
  } else {
    if (sections[currentSectionIndex].getBoundingClientRect().top > 80) {
      currentSectionIndex--;
    }
  }

  const currentActive = document.querySelector('nav a.actives');
  if (currentActive) {
    currentActive.classList.remove('actives');
  }

  const newActive = document.querySelectorAll('nav a')[currentSectionIndex];
  newActive.classList.add('actives');
});
</script>
```

CSS code:

```
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

nav a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav a.actives {
  color: #f00; /* active link color */
}
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Regards,
Eric

I've tried dozens of ways, but I haven't been able to achieve the effect where the sticky menu will change colors when scrolling the page.

EDIT.

Adds missing html

```
    <nav role="navigation" data-scroll-offset="400" data-scroll-spy="true">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section4">Section 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

EDIT2

Link to (jsfiddle.net) - https://jsfiddle.net/SwiezaStrona/ptkaLe49/4/#save

Comment: Where is your HTML. Please provide all the relevant code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Indeed, I forgot to add the HTML code. I added it at the end of the question.

Comment: You are querying `section`, but nowhere in the HTML has a mention of it. Can you please update you code here (https://jsfiddle.net/) so that anyone from the community can assist you better?

Comment: @SanthoshJohn thank you for your answer.
Please tell me how to share the link to (jsfiddle.net).
Should I paste it as a comment?

My questions may seem stupid, but it's my first time posting something on this site and I don't know the rules yet ;)

Comment: You can directly share the url. To better align with StackOverflow, paste the same in the below code area provided by SO.

Comment: @SanthoshJohn thank you very much for your answer. The link is already added ;)